# Why is $\pi/2$ omitted from the solution of $\cot x = 3 \sin 2x$?

Tags: trigonometry

> Why is it that the solution of 
>   $$\cot x = 3 \sin 2x \quad(\text{for the interval}\; -\pi  < x < \pi)$$
>   does not include $\pi/2$, even though if this is graphed, it shows intersections at $x = \pm\pi/2$?

Please see graph below. (The solutions mentioned are only four, to the exclusion of positive and negative $\pi/2$.)

[image]

Algebraically as well, one of the factors comes out to be $\cos x = 0$ (which should give $x = \pi/2$). (Hence the graph.)

[image]

Comment: Maybe since it is considered a trivial solution.

Comment: Without additional assumptions, I see no reason why $\pm \pi/2$ should be any less worth than the other solutions.

Comment: It could be a simple oversight on the part of the author ... not unlike the oversight by the illustrator who labeled the cotangent graph as "$y=\cos\theta$". :)

Comment: If that's a screenshot of the textbook's working of the problem, it does explicitly mention $\theta=\pm \pi/2$ as solutions (although they left off the "$\pm$" when giving decimal approximations). It looks like someone simply forgot to include them with the other values in "the answer". All things considered, it could be that this book just didn't have a very good proofreader.

Comment: The values are indicated among the solutions for $\cos \theta=0 \implies \theta =\pm \pi/2$

Answer (score 1):

You are right the values $x=\pm \frac{\pi}2$ are solutions of the equation

$$\cot x=3 \sin 3x \implies \cot \pm\frac{\pi}2=3 \sin \pm\pi=0$$

maybe it was not included since it is considered a trivial solution.

**added after editing**

The values $x=\pm \frac{\pi}2$ seem to be indeed included among the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for not including $x=\pm \pi/2$ in the intersection set.

Surprisingly enough they have the $x=\pm \pi/2$ as solultions but they did not list them as solutions because of the quadrant confusion.

Which quadrant are $x=\pm \pi/2??$ in??