# Why are these two solutions not included in the solution of $\tan 2x = 2$?

Tags: trigonometry

The question asks to solve, in the interval $-180° \leq x < 180°$, the equation:

$$\sin x (\cos x + \csc x) = 2 \cos^2 (x)$$

This equation simplifies to

$$\tan 2x = 2$$

According to this, $2x$ (with a domain multiplied by $2$ to become $-360° \leq x < 360°$) must be the following: $63.43°, 243.43°, -116.57°,$ and $-296.57°$.
And therefore, after dividing by $2$, x must be: $31.7°, 121.7°, -58.3°, -148.3°$

However, the answer excludes these two: $121.7°$ and $-148.3°$

I don't understand why.

Comment: If you're pulling this from the source of your [last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2976738/why-is-pi-2-omitted-from-the-solution-of-cot-x-3-sin-2x), then I think it's safe to say it's an oversight on the book's part.

Comment: What book is this? People may want to avoid it. :)